# How do you center your main window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, center

I have a WPF application and I need to know how to center the wain window programatically (not in XAML).

I need to be able to do this both at startup and in response to certain user events. It has to be dynamically calculated since the window size itself is dynamic.

What's the simplest way to do this? Under old Win32 code, I'd call the system metrics functions and work it all out. Is that still the way it's done or is there a simple `CenterWindowOnScreen()` function I can now call.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
private void CenterWindowOnScreen()
{
    double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    double windowWidth = this.Width;
    double windowHeight = this.Height;
    this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
    this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
}
```

You can use this method to set the window position to the center of your screen.

Comment: I'll give you one for that but I seem to recall it's a lot more work, taking into account task bars and so forth. Still, +1 for the `SystemParameters` and some code so I don't have to go out to `GetSystemMetrics` myself.

Comment: Possibly the only way to re-center the window after programmatically changing the window Height and/or Width or after its location has been changed.

Comment: This only works if you have 1 monitor, or if all your monitors are the same size

Comment: A little distributive property of division because division is more expensive in the way of performance than substraction:" this.Left = (screenWidth - windowWidth)/2;" etc...

Comment: does not work for me with multiple monitors. it ends up being quite off center

Answer (score 105):

Well, for startup time, you can set the [startup location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx):

```
window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

Later, you'll need to query it.  The information (at least for the primary screen) is available via [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth.aspx)/Height.

Answer (score 88):

Isn't it just as simple to set

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

In the XAML definition for the window.

Comment: That's fine for the startup location but, as I pointed out in the question, I also want to do this from within the program when the window changes size.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. I wondered why so many people seemed to go for the non obvious solution. :-)

Answer (score 27):

I had to combine a few of these answers to cover all bases in my case:

- [Peter's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25525307/345659) to find the current monitor - rather than the just the Primary monitor (seriously who has just 1 monitor at work anymore?)
- @[Wild_A's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14334262/345659) to use the `workarea` rather than the `screen bounds` to take into account the space for the taskbar.
- I had to add DPI scaling, specifically for a tablet displaying 1280x800 as 1024x640, but which is useful to cover edge cases, for which I found an answer for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15281714/345659). Note the `dpiScaling` variable is null if called on first load before the UI is displayed ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503307/345659))

```cs
//get the current monitor
Screen currentMonitor = Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle);

//find out if our app is being scaled by the monitor
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow);
double dpiScaling = (source != null && source.CompositionTarget != null ? source.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.M11 : 1);

//get the available area of the monitor
Rectangle workArea = currentMonitor.WorkingArea;
var workAreaWidth = (int)Math.Floor(workArea.Width*dpiScaling);
var workAreaHeight = (int)Math.Floor(workArea.Height*dpiScaling);

//move to the centre
Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = (((workAreaWidth - (myWindowWidth * dpiScaling)) / 2) + (workArea.Left * dpiScaling));
Application.Current.MainWindow.Top = (((workAreaHeight - (myWindowHeight * dpiScaling)) / 2) + (workArea.Top * dpiScaling));
```

where `myWindowWidth` and `myWindowHeight` are variables I used to manually set the size of the window earlier.

Comment: I have just one monitor - 40" with 4K resolution.  Can't see why anyone would need more than one (or who would have more desk space). ;)

Comment: @CramerTV Ha true! The times they are a changing :)  Although still relevant for plugging into a monitor for demos

Comment: Great combination of two answers, just used this and it worked perfectly. And yes I used 3 screens- one with Visual Studio, one with a pdf(ebook), one with stackoverflow/outlook

Comment: This should definitively be the answer

Answer (score 22):

```
Rect workArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
this.Left = (workArea.Width - this.Width) / 2 + workArea.Left;
this.Top = (workArea.Height - this.Height) / 2 + workArea.Top;
```

This takes into account the taskbar size (by using `System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea`) and position (by adding `workArea.Left` and `workArea.Top`)

Comment: This only works if you have 1 monitor, or if all your monitors are the same size

Answer (score 8):

In case you need to draw a window in an multiple screen environment.
I've made a static class where the following method can be re-used:

```
public static void PostitionWindowOnScreen(Window window, double horizontalShift = 0, double verticalShift = 0)
{
    Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
    window.Left = screen.Bounds.X + ((screen.Bounds.Width - window.ActualWidth) / 2) + horizontalShift;
    window.Top = screen.Bounds.Y + ((screen.Bounds.Height - window.ActualHeight) / 2) + verticalShift;        
}
```

In the constructor of the Window now just call the method:

```
this.Loaded += (s, a) => Globals.PostitionWindowOnScreen(this, 0, 0)
```

Comment: For some reason, this method positions my window 20 pixels away from the top? This is working better for me than the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4):

As a basic solution, you can use the window's StartupLocation property, set it to one of the enum values defined in System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation enumeration, there is one for center of screen:

```
_wpfWindow.StartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

Unfortunately it's not always quite so simple; you need to account for multiple monitors, taskbars, etc.  The "CenterScreen" option opens the window in the center of the screen that has the mouse cursor.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512398/showing-a-window-with-wpf-winforms-and-dual-monitors) for a lot of information, or reference the [api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation(VS.90).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In the window element just add this attribute-value pair:
**WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"**

Comment: "Programatically, _not_ in XAML". In any case, isn't this just a duplicate of naskew's answer?

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I am working in a shop where we do everything in xaml. The "programmatic" way is clever, but is not the WPF way.

Comment: So, @James, what is the WPF way to increase your windows size and still keep it centered? The specific use case I had was a 80x24 terminal window for which you could change the font size. In order to maintain visible 80x24 characters, the window size had to increase but I wanted to keep it centered.

Answer (score 3):

What I am using in my app, it is working for multiple displays and for different DPI setting

```
    //center a window on chosen screen
    public static void CenterWindow(Window w, System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen = null)
    {
        if(screen == null)
            screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;

        int screenW = screen.Bounds.Width;
        int screenH = screen.Bounds.Height;
        int screenTop = screen.Bounds.Top;
        int screenLeft = screen.Bounds.Left;

        w.Left = PixelsToPoints((int)(screenLeft + (screenW - PointsToPixels(w.Width, "X")) / 2), "X");
        w.Top = PixelsToPoints((int)(screenTop + (screenH - PointsToPixels(w.Height, "Y")) / 2), "Y");
    }

    public static double PixelsToPoints(int pixels, string direction)
    {
        if (direction == "X")
        {
            return pixels * SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            return pixels * SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        }
    }

    public static double PointsToPixels(double wpfPoints, string direction)
    {
        if (direction == "X")
        {
            return wpfPoints * System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            return wpfPoints * System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Wild_A answer I just subscribed to the `SizeChanged` event, and added this event handler:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Rect workArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        this.Left = (workArea.Width - e.NewSize.Width) / 2 + workArea.Left;
        this.Top = (workArea.Height - e.NewSize.Height) / 2 + workArea.Top;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ... Handel exception; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

And in case you only want to center horizontally / vertically, You can override the OnActivated method and set left or top to zero like this:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        // to center Vertically
        Left = 0;
        // or user top = 0 to center Horizontally
        //top = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another short way to make mainwindow render at center of the computer screen using code behind.

```
this.Left = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - this.Width)/2;
this.Top = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - this.Height)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy-paste good quality extension code.

Runtime:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="Window"/> extensions.
    /// </summary>
    public static class WindowExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Moves the window to the center of the current screen, also considering dpi.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="window"></param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        public static void MoveToCenter(this Window window)
        {
            window = window ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(window));

            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
            var screen = Screen.FromHandle(helper.Handle);
            var area = screen.WorkingArea;

            var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(window);
            var dpi = source?.CompositionTarget?.TransformFromDevice.M11 ?? 1.0;

            window.Left = dpi * area.Left + (dpi * area.Width - window.Width) / 2;
            window.Top = dpi * area.Top + (dpi * area.Height - window.Height) / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Initial position:

```xml
<Window WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to property window of MainWindow.xaml

- find **WindowStartupLocation** property from Common category
- select **CenterScreen** option from dropdown
- Run the Application

**For Full Screen**

Go to property window of MainWindow.xaml

- find **WindowState** property from Common category
- select **Maximized** option from dropdown
- Run the Application

Answer (score -1):

You will have to **find** this line :
**Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"**

And you **add** this line to it : 
**WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"**

To become this : 
        **Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">**

Thank me Later ♥

Answer (score -2):

If you it to be maximized at once
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;