# Center Window on Resize using Caliburn Micro in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro, My UserControl(Window) is intially in Center Screen but as content loaded into it dynamically, its size increases.

So i want to make the window in Centre Screen when it resizes.

Comment: While this idea may sound good at first, the real-world usability is awful. What will happen when the user moves the window to a different area of the screen and then more content is loaded into the window? Should the window move back to the center of the screen?

Comment: So when does it move to the centre of the screen?

Comment: i have an grouped datagrid.. when i expand that datagrid rows.its size gets changed. at that time, i need to update the window to centre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I do not agree with the usability of moving a window in general, here is what you'd do to re-center your window if the window has been resized:

1. Create a `SizeChanged` event handler.
2. In the event handler, [re-center the window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4019831/9664)

Comment: i was asking using caliburn micro

Comment: Caliburn Micro has nothing to do with window placement; CM provides a framework for UI patterns and MVVM conventions. How you display the content is up to you.