# Problems with PrimaryScreen.Size

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been fine with `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size` for some time, but on my Windows7 computer attached to my big-screen TV it is giving me incorrect values.

I read elsewhere to try `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize` but that gives the same values.

When I right click the desktop to get Screen Resolution, it says `1920x1080`.  The above two are giving me `1280x720`.

I've also tried the WPF versions:

```
var w = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
var h = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
MessageBox.Show(new Size((int)w, (int)h).ToString());
```

The display size has been changed via the (right click the desktop) `Personalize > Desktop` options to be 150% (since the screen is 60" and you sit kind of far away).

How to detect this so the value's returned from the above can be adjusted?

**Note**: I've discovered how to get around this with a right-click executable and adjust the compatability to disable DPI virtualization, but I still need a programatic solution so I don't have to have user's adjust this themselves: See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660(VS.85).aspx#dpi_virtualization

Comment: @Grant What do you mean?  The screen resolution is `1920x1080`, there is no secondary display.  The computer is not a laptop.

Comment: At 150%, you explicitly have to tell Windows that you are DPI aware on don't need to be lied to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms high DPI blurry fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/winforms-high-dpi-blurry-fonts)

Comment: @HansPassant So there is no way to detect this from within the application?  I've tried setting the manifest to test that, but I get a null error in a core lib.

Comment: @HansPassant I copied the manifest from the link over my manifest, and get the error "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: activationContext"

Comment: You did something wrong, hard to guess.  The linked duplicate also shows how to do it without a manifest.  There's no point in "detecting it", your app is either dpi aware or it isn't.

Comment: @HansPassant It must be, because I created a new WinForms project, did the exact same thing and it runs w/o the error.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem in Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't feel this is a duplicate question, but the answer is the same as on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/353147  As the question isn't about blurry fonts but why Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size returns faulty information.  It could help others.

I did run into an error message, that mscorlib threw an null error.  From this thread http://forums.asp.net/t/1653876.aspx/1 I was able to discover that unchecking "Enable ClickOnce security settings" fixed it.  This seems like a hack, but it works.

Comment: First link is best solution, it solved my problem in 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 6):

It could be your `Dpi` setting in windows set above 100%

Try using this method, this will scale the resolution to the current system Dpi settings

Winforms:

```
private Size GetDpiSafeResolution()
{
    using (Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        return new Size((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * (int)graphics.DpiX) / 96
          , (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * (int)graphics.DpiY) / 96);
    }
}
```

WPF:

```
private Size GetDpiSafeResolution()
{
    PresentationSource _presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow);
    Matrix matix = _presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
    return new System.Windows.Size(
        System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * matix.M22,
        System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * matix.M11);
}
```

**Note:** Make sure your MainWindow is loaded before running this code

Comment: This is a winforms application, so I'm having troubles getting Application.Current

Comment: sorry I thought it was wpf :(

Comment: Updated my answer with Winforms version (untested). But its the same idea, you need to find the Dpi setting and mutiply the size by that

Comment: Thx, why do you declare the two float dpiX and dpiY values but don't use them?

Comment: That's not helping, that just multiplies 1280 by 96 and 720 by 96.  They need to be multiplied by 1.5

Comment: Can you test my latest version, I cant test as I cant restart my PC right now to change my Dpi, (sorry i am bad at math and this confused me a bit LOL)

Comment: I tried that already, but graphics.DpiX is 96.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: oh so you dpi is 96, hmm Then I wonder why you get the wrong value from `Screen.PrimaryScreen`

Comment: Right, all that is happening (from what I gather from the dialog box) is that items are just getting increased 150%, the screen itself isn't changing.  Yet the normal way to get the screen size is smaller - for whatever reason.

Comment: Try setting this in the Form constructor `AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;`

Comment: I thought about trying that, as it is an imperfect solution (if it worked) - but it doesn't help - just tested it.

Comment: Its been so long since I have used winforms, sorry i could not help :(

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, please don't delete this as there is valuable information we discussed in our comments that might help others.

Comment: Thanks again, just tried the WPF answer. It's great, but the width & height were backwards, edited the answer to correct it.