# VB.NET Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height or Width returns incorrect value on Surface 3

Tags: vb.net

Trying to scale a few parts of a VB.NET WinForms program I have been working on. I was trying to do it based on resolution but ran into an issue on the Surface 3.

```
Public Sub GetScreenRes()
    Dim screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    Dim screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
    MessageBox.Show("Your Screen Resolution is " & screenHeight & "x" & screenWidth)
End Sub

'Output on the message box is "Your screen resolution is 1440 x 960"
'Output should be "Your screen resolution is 2160 x 1440"
```

I have double checked and the resolution on the Surface 3 is set at 2160x1440.

Thought it might be an issue with DPI so I tried this to check

```
Dim dpiX As Single
Dim dpiY As Single

Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    dpiX = g.DpiX
    dpiY = g.DpiY
End Using

MessageBox.Show(dpiX & " - " & dpiY)

'Output from that is 96 - 96
```

A DPI of 32 is the same as my desktop screen. And all of this code returns the correct numbers on my desktop.

I went to this site http://dpi.lv/ and adjusted the diagonal size to 23" for my desktop and it gives me 96 DPI.  Went on the surface and set the diagonal size to 12" and it gives me a DPI of 216.

Comment: 32 x 32 for your DPI?  Are you using a [Lite-Brite](http://www.hasbro.com/litebrite/en_US/)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 96 x 96

Comment: have you read through - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281714/problems-with-primaryscreen-size

Comment: Yeah I looked through it, and I have tried some of the answers but I end up with correct numbers on the Surface 3 and incorrect on my desktop.

Comment: On the surface if I take the width and multiply by dpi then divide by 64, I get 2160.  but on my desktop, I get 2880 which is wrong.  Don't ask where the 64 came from, I know it is supposed to be 216. I think it is scaling everything back 33.3333% but not sure how to correct this in my code.

Comment: A little extra info, if I go into the display settings and adjust the "Make it easier to read what's on your screen" to the smallest setting so you really cannot read anything without a magnifying glass, I get the correct values.  So how do we detect this scale setting in Windows?

Comment: Have you tried setting your app as DPI aware?

Comment: @LarsTech, that was pretty darned funny! Wished I knew how to solve this sizing issue, though. I've run into it before. In the end I just gave up.