# How to re-center a wpf view that changes size

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a main window view that hosts other views created as UserControls and placed in a ContentControl.

I've set:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

This works fine for the initial view - but when the content changes to a larger view it resizes to fit it but doesn't 're-center' the window. How do I get the main window to re-center?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019831/how-do-you-center-your-main-window-in-wpf), try following solution

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Rect workArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    this.Left = (workArea.Width - this.Width) / 2 + workArea.Left;
    this.Top = (workArea.Height - this.Height) / 2 + workArea.Top;
}
```