# Centering screen causes parts of the window go out off screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using this in `XAML` to center the screen,

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

To center the window on the users screen, but when the screen resolution is quite small the `Title Bar` is out of the screen range. Obviously when this happens, the users can't close down the program and on particularly small screens some of the `Tab Controls` are not visible.

How do I make the screen center along with always showing the `Title Bar`?

Comment: You mean you need to resize your window to fit the screen resolution before moving the window to the center of screen?

Comment: @grek40, I want to keep the window size, but make sure that the title is always visible. Unless I should be adjusting the window size to suit the screen???

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem, but Alt-F4 will close the window that has focus even if the title bar is off screen.

Comment: @Kevin, unfortunately you can't tell every user what to do.

Comment: For what you are asking, you aren't going to be able to use CenterScreen. You'll have to determine the screen dimentions and calculate a top/left point on the screen that gives you the visibility you want, then move the screen location to that point.

Comment: @Kevin, I feared as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make the screen center along with always showing the Title Bar?

You will have to programmatically adjust the size of the window. You could for example set the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties based on the `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` and `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` values respectively:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MaxHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - SystemParameters.CaptionHeight;
        MaxWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    }
}
```

You could also refer to the following question:

[How do you center your main window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019831/how-do-you-center-your-main-window-in-wpf)