# Center window programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the page width and height in page loaded, When I change the size the page size change but the windows does not appear in center screen, Even when I but in xaml code :

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

The code I used in code behind in window load is:

```
 this.Width = 1366;
 this.Height = 768;
```

This Answer provide a method to center window Programmatically, But I wonder why the following do not work :

```
this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

Any suggest
Thanks

Comment: Set the Width and Height attributes in the XAML. When you set `WindowStartupLocation`, you should expect that to set the location of the window at startup. You should not expect it to keep updating the window location forever unless the property is called `KeepUpdatingWindowLocationForever`. If you really want code to do that, [here's some code to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022379/424129).

Comment: I want to change the size according to some conditions, that is why I put it in code behind

Comment: You could try binding. Or you could just copy and paste [the window centering method from the answer I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022379/424129) and call that every time you change width and height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you center your main window in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019831/how-do-you-center-your-main-window-in-wpf)