# WindowStartupLocation ignored when starting minimized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**(The proposed duplicate deals with a Window that starts with `WindowState.Normal`.)**

If an application has

```
WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

and starts with

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

and only then has

```
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

The Window is **not** shown in the center of the screen.

Is there a way to fix this besides manually calculating the screen's center?

Comment: Considering the property is `WindowStartupLocation` and you start it minimized, this makes sense to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you center your main window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019831/how-do-you-center-your-main-window-in-wpf)

Comment: The question specifically precludes any solutions in the "duplicate".

Comment: @Andy Actually, no.  Title vs title, perhaps, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019865/1633308) does state the reality of OP's problem.

Comment: @DonBoitnott No. Nominally that answer assumes a later time as opposed to ***the first time*** the Window is shown. I'm referring to the first time the Windows is shown.

Comment: @ispiro No, you're not.  By definition, once the window is in its minimized state, startup is over.  So, yes, it _is later_ that you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to start the window center screen, but minimise it before it is actually shown on the screen, like this:

```
WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
SourceInitialized += (s, e) => WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

The `SourceInitialized` event is raised after the window position is set, but before it is shown.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  As the property suggests, it's a *startup location*, not one that is applied at every transition of `WindowState`.  Once it's been displayed, you calculate.

Comment: `Once it's been displayed, you calculate.` - Yes. But my question _is_ about the first time.

Comment: @ispiro That makes no sense.  The window is displayed.  Startup over.  Once you set `WindowState` later, it's _no longer startup_, therefore the property does not apply.  You cannot wish it so.

Comment: Even if you're right, after a Window is in a certain location, minimizing and normalizing it will show it in the same location again. This should have happened here.