# Trouble creating a WPF window in a secondary monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm working on implementing some Chrome-like tab functionality in an app and am having some trouble getting the new instance to spawn correctly.  I've done quite a bit of searching and iterating over various solutions but have not yet been able to make a new window spawn on the second monitor.

Here's the use thread:

1. Open file
2. Drag current tab to other monitor
3. New App instance spawns with that tab set in it, at the location that the user dragged the tab to.

The disconnect is in step 3.  The new instance is always spawned on the Primary monitor.

So, some code to expand upon the problem.

```
namespace app {
    public class AppView {
      public void OpenInNewWindow()
      {
        // Create a new viewmodel
        var appViewModel = new AppVM();

        //// On my machine this returns the correct screen "DISPLAY2".  The Top and Left properties are 0 and 1680, respectively.
        var targetScreen = Screen.FromPoint(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);

        ////So we can set the position of the new view
        var appView = new AppView(appViewModel);

        //This seats the currently selected data tab inside the new AppViewModel
        RelocateSelectedViewModel(appViewModel);

        appView.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        appView.Top = targetScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
        appView.Left = targetScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
        appView.Show();
        // Have to maximize after we Show() or it won't appera on secondary monitors according to THE INTERNET!
        appView.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        appView.Focus();            
      }
    }
}
```

I suppose I should mention that I have no problems getting the second Screen.  targetScreen in the code above is correctly finding the screen I want, and the Top and Left values of the new window are getting set correctly, to 0 and 1680, respectively.  It's just that the AppView.Show()  command (which is actually Window.Show()) creates the window on the primary screen.

I have taken this same code to a standalone project and it has worked, which leads me to believe that there is some kind of tie between my new appView and the current one that is overriding my sets here.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Have you got this property set incorrectly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx

Comment: @todda.speot.is Manual is default, so it is set properly.

Comment: @todda.speot.is in a previous revision of the code I had set it to Manual.  I'll go ahead and add it back in for clarity.

Comment: It's the default, but it doesn't mean that it's not set somewhere else. We don't have the code for the constructors -- see `new AppVM` and `new AppView`.

Comment: For purposes of the discussion the only thing that happens in the constructors of these two classes is some collection initialization and reading from Preference files that don't change the look of the application.

Comment: If the constructors are more or less empty than they're blank windows? Note if you're calling `InitializeComponent` a whole bunch of settings are being applied to your window. You may want to check that there isn't some junk in the XAML for the window that's causing this behaviour.

Comment: @todda.speot.is I'm an idiot. I overlooked how the XAML was setting WindowState=Maximized and WindowStartupLocation=CenterScreen.  Once I removed that it all worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using the Winforms [`Screen.FromControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol.aspx)? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/512691/175679).

You can try this hack from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151949/175679):

```
appView.SourceInitialized += (_, __) => appView.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
appView.Show();
```

Comment: I suppose I should mention that I have no problems getting the second Screen.  targetScreen in the code above is correctly finding the screen I want, and the Top and Left values of the new window are getting set correctly, to 0 and 1680, respectively.  It's just that the AppView.Show()  command (which is actually Window.Show()) creates the window on the primary screen :(

Comment: Are you setting the window owner? What if you remove the `WindowState.Maximized`?

Comment: I'm not setting the Owner as of yet.  Do I want to null it out so it gets treated like a top-level Window, or did you have something else in mind? Oh, I've read that post before...the SourceInitialized didn't work then which is why I added the discrete call to set WindowState after the Show call returns.  Neither of these work in my case.

Comment: The root of the issue was the XAML was setting WindowState and WindowStartupLocation independently of my sets in the codebehind.  Once I removed those everything fell into place.