# Load two windows on two separate screens

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a WPF presentation application where the Primary Window on the Primary Screen will be used to update the content on the Presentation Window, which needs to be on the secondary screen. I am looking for samples or code snippet that can help me do that.

[image]

Also I have attempted the following and doesn't work:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
            if (screens.Length > 1)
            {
                var window = new MainWindow
                {
                    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual,
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized,

                    Top = screens[0].WorkingArea.Top,
                    Left = screens[0].WorkingArea.Left,
                    Topmost = true
                };
                window.Show();

                var pesentationWindow = new PresentationWindow
                {
                    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual,
                    ShowInTaskbar = false,
                    Top = screens[1].WorkingArea.Top,
                    Left = screens[1].WorkingArea.Left,
                    Topmost = true
                };
                pesentationWindow.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do what? Create two windows? Move them?

Comment: Wouldn't we need to know the size/position of your monitors?

Comment: There is something about from luke payne: http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/articles/programming-tutorials/multi-monitor-programming-in-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Screen object in this way

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Window1 w1 = new Window1();
    Window2 w2 = new Window2();


    Screen s1 = Screen.AllScreens[0];
    Screen s2 = Screen.AllScreens[1];

    Rectangle r1 = s1.WorkingArea;
    Rectangle r2 = s2.WorkingArea;

    w1.Top = r1.Top;
    w1.Left = r1.Left;

    w2.Top = r2.Top;
    w2.Left = r2.Left;

    w1.Show();
    w2.Show();

    w2.Owner = w1;


}
```

Follow this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5d181304-8952-4663-8c3c-dc4d986aa8dd) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) static property you can figure out how many screens there are and what their resolutions are. Figure out which is the `PrimaryScreen` and set the secondary Window to the correct size and position. **See for more info: [Trouble creating a WPF window in a secondary monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362865/trouble-creating-a-wpf-window-in-a-secondary-monitor)**

Then simply create two separate Window classes that bind your DataContext's bindings differently. For Example:

```
class DataContext
{
   public string Header { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<Window Title="Primary Window">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Header}"/>
</Window>
```

```xml
<Window Title="Presentation Window">
  <TextBlock Content="{Binding Header}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: That's not what I want, I want the physical location of the two windows on two separate monitors.

Comment: Sorry you edited in the rest of your question, which made it hard for me to answer.

Comment: Apologies from my end. i realized afterwards that I should have provide more detail information.